# Unable to upload app to iTunes connect. WatchKit 1 issue?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit, apple-watch

I have just tried to submit a build of my app to iTunes connect and I am unable to via Xcode. Via Application loader the app will upload but then I receive an email stating the binary is invalid due to invalid watchkit support.

```
Invalid WatchKit Support - The WatchKitSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
```

The application contains a watch os1 app which has been in the app for over a year without much update. The application has been updated several times since the watch app was added without any issues.

I have a strong feeling this is related to the upcoming requirement for watchOS Apps.

```
Starting June 1, 2016, all new watchOS apps submitted to the App Store must be native apps built with the watchOS 2 SDK or later.
```

However it is more than one day early... Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I guess by the time it gets through review, it will be after June 1...?

Comment: You need to go to build phases and make sure you WatchKitApplication is listed under "Embedded -> Destination=Plugins; Name=WatchAppName.appex"

Comment: @Brandon it is already there. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Tried to upload again now and it went through OK. Maybe apple flicked the switch to early? Time will tell.

Comment: @bencallis i am getting same error as yours...but I am not able to upload my build to itunesconnect...have you got any proper workaround for this issue?